# HTML link with title of item . How is it work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, href

I am new in web development. I am learning about it. I have a confusion. Help me please.
I saw that many site use **href** link in ***a*** tag  with item title. My confusion is that how to work this link address whenever this titled html file not exist in directories.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post a sample of what you are talking about to help others understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the title attribute like this :

```
<a href="#" title="title">Link></a>
```

Comment: Ok fine .. I want to say about permalink